# How to return result of chained async functions?

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript 3.7.

Given the standard concept of command and command handler as defined here, with the handler being potentially asynchronous:

```
export type Command = { name: string; body: any };
export type CommandHandler<TCommand extends Command, TResult = any> = (cmd: TCommand) => TResult | Promise<TResult>;
```

I'm trying to a create a function which, given an array of command handlers, will return a new command handler that effectively invokes each handler *sequentially* and returns the result of the last executed handler, thereby allowing any handler to interrupt the handler chain.

I would expect something like this to work:

```
export const chain = <TCommand extends Command, TResult = any>(
  ...handlers: CommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>[]
): CommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> => async cmd => {
  let result: TResult;
  for (const handler of handlers) {
    result = await handler(cmd);
  }

  return result;
};
```

but the compiler is giving me this error: `Variable 'result' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)`

Why isn't this working and how should I go about organizing this code?

Comment: Will [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) help? Pass in an array of promises and it returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises have been fulfilled,

Comment: Wouldn't Promise.all execute all handlers in parallel and wait for all of them to be fulfilled? In my case, I want handlers to be executed sequentially, so that any given handler can interrupt the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `handlers` is empty, TypeScript understands this as `let result: TResult; return result`, which returns `undefined`. `any` is rubbish and [effectively disables TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#gradual-typing).

> *TypeScript uses the type `any` whenever it can’t tell what the type of an expression should be. Compared to `Dynamic`, calling `any` a type is an overstatement. It just turns off the type checker wherever it appears.*

Consider this alternative -

```
type Command<T> =
  { name: string; body: T }

type CommandHandler<T> =
  (cmd: Command<T>) => Promise<T | void>

function chain <T>(...handlers: Array<CommandHandler<T>>): CommandHandler<T>
{ return async (cmd: Command<T>): Promise<T | void> =>
  { let r
    for (const h of handlers)
      r = await h(cmd)
    return r
  }
}
```

Because we defined the return type of `chain` as `CommandHandler<T>` we don't even need the extra type hints around the `async` function -

```
type Command<T> =
  { name: string; body: T }

type CommandHandler<T> =
  (cmd: Command<T>) => Promise<T | void>

function chain <T>(...handlers: Array<CommandHandler<T>>): CommandHandler<T>
{ return async cmd =>  // <-- cmd inferred as Command<T>
  { let r
    for (const h of handlers)
      r = await h(cmd)
    return r // <-- inferred T | void
  }
}
```

Demo: verify the results in this [typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMA8AVAfFAXgFgAoKKAbylWQQgC4oBnYAJwEtUBzAbigCM46EI2xQAPlABucduigBfUqVCRYiFBgASadABsIrHPmJkoACgDGCdI3hJdxgJSF8ABVaJ2TCDgnTZdFxlEgAzAFdUS2B2OFQoSwALZE4oY3MAOizkjANWJkYAQVZWZBBMe010HVzDY1wnOw1dGv06vFIqVghgcNZ45CYQKISbV1JyKgNgKFYJ8ihQuFYLSziWKESoOFDN3TymJ3mF2cIoZAB3FJnEqxsjs3Ju3v7Z+aUSD6A)

---

**flexible return type**

If you want your `CommandHandler`s to return a potentially different type, you can use two *type variables* -

```js
type Command<T> =
  { name: string; body: T }

type CommandHandler<T,R> =                 // <--
  (cmd: Command<T>) => Promise<R | void>
```

And heres' the updated `chain`. Now we can have an output type that differs from the input command type -

```
function chain <T,R>(...handlers: Array<CommandHandler<T,R>>): CommandHandler<T,R>
{ return async cmd =>  // <-- cmd inferred as Command<T>
  { let r
    for (const h of handlers)
      r = await h(cmd)
    return r // <-- inferred R | void
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue in my code is not related to types but rather to the "result" variable being used being assigned, when visibly it's only used as the return type. It must be related to the way async/await was used, but I can't really put my finger on it.

Comment: Actually you're right, if handlers is empty, result is being returned (and therefore used) without having been assigned beforehand. Declaring result as TResult | undefined and the chain function return type to CommandHandler<TCommand, TResult | undefined> works as intended. Nothing related to async/await. Thanks.

Comment: TypeScript is able to make all sorts of surprising conclusions about your code. You should still remove instances of `any` from your program. In an edit, I show how you can get a different return type from the `CommandHandler`, if that's what you're after. The many uses of `extends`, `any` and `|` in your program are code smells.